# MySQL SELECT multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

If I need all rows from multiple **completely unrelated** tables, is it more efficient to run a single `SELECT` query?

So the result returned could be like:

```
[{ table: "table1", id: 1 }, 
 { table: "table1", id: 2 },
 { table: "table2", code: 1 }]
```

Or would it be just as efficient as running separate `SELECT` query for each of the table?

Comment: Use `UNION`:    E.g. `SELECT ... UNION SELECT   .. ;`

Comment: Typically you _can't_ return all rows from two or more arbitrary tables in a single query, unless they can be UNIONed together in a meaningful way.  From a data transfer usage point of view, it doesn't matter whether you use or two queries, because the same number of records need to be transferred in either case.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select column1,column2 
from table1,table2
where table1.id = table2.id
```

It's better to have a single query to retrieve the data. Also, you can use joins for retrieving data from two tables.

Comment: The 2 tables are completely unrelated, with different columns (and different number of them).